# comparision within same array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

Consider a 2 dimensional array arr,

```
         col1    col2   col3  
    row1   12      1      6
    row2   30      21     10
    row3   91      39     40
    row4   76      1      70
    row5   30      21     10
```

i want to compare between rows to get the occurance of each row so tat the col1,2,3 values are all same for the other one also .. so in above the occurance values are,

```
   for row1 it is  1,for row2 =  2,row3 =  1,row4 = 1,row5 =2 ..
   in above row2 and row5 occur twice having same col values..
```

**I implemented the code and im getting output also but the problem is im having nearly 50000 rows, so it takes 5 mins to compute..i want a method or code tat computes faster..**        This is my code

```
for i=1:n
  for j=i+1:n
     if( (ar(i,1)==ar(j,1))&& (ar(i,2)== ar(j,2)) && (ar(i,3)==ar(j,3))) 
     //stores occurances in index position 4     
      ar(i,4)=ar(i,4)+1;
      ar(j,4)=ar(j,4)+1;
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: You will need some HashTable? What is the range of the values in the table? Small int?

Comment: Using of HashTable makes it more complicated i guess??.. and range is 0 to 255..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** map each row into a single integer

each element is a byte, so each row can be uniquely mapped into 3 bytes.

```
ar = 2.^ar;
ar = ar(:, 1) + 256 * ar(:, 2) + 256^2 * ar(:, 3);
```

will convert your table into a single column, then use `hist`.

**Option 2:** use `containers.Map`

This is the Matlab's hash table (only supported for recent versions). You'll need to convert each row into a string first.